# Does this subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ form a subgroup?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-groups

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. Consider the abelian group $N = \mathbb{Z}e_1\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_n$.

Assume that $A$ is any nilpotent linear operator acting on $V$ with $Ae_1 = 0$. Also let $G\subseteq \mathrm{GL}_n(V)$ is an (algebraic) group acting on $V$ with fixed point $e_1$. For each $g\in G$ let $t_g\in\mathbb{Q}$ be not zero number with minimal absolute value such that $t_gg^{-1}Ag(N)\subseteq N$.

Is it true that $$\mathbb{Z}e_1\cap\bigcup_{g\in G}t_gg^{-1}Ag(N)$$ is additive subgroup of $N$ if

a) $G\cong(\mathbb{Q},+)$

b) $G\cong(\mathbb{Q}^*,*)$?

*Remark.* In the case a) we have that $G = \{\exp(tB) | t\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ for some nilpotent matrix $B$ with $Be_1 = 0$.

Comment: Two questions: (1) Why does $t_g$ exist? Actually, when $n=1$ or more generally if $A = 0$, then every $t_g$ satisfies $t_g g^{-1} A g(N) \subseteq N$, so the inf of them is 0, so at least in this case the definition requires at least a tweak. (2) Is there any reason to think that either condition (a) or (b) is a particularly interesting case of the question? For instance, is there some $G$ which (a) / (b) is meant to rule out, being an obvious counterexample or something?

Comment: If $T_g = \{t\in\mathbb{Q} | tg^{-1}Ag(N)\subseteq N\}$, then it is not empty and is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$. So it should be cyclic with generator $t_g$. In the case $T_g = 0$ it possible to define $t_g = 0$. Number $t_g$ can be defined for each $g\in GL_n(V)$ and so for each $g\in GL_n(V)$ we can define $n_A(g)$ as the generator of the group $\mathbb{Z}e_1\cap t_gg^{-1}Ag(N)$. For me it is interesting to find $g\in GL_n(V)$ with smallest $n_A(g)$. So the main idea is to consider the subgroups $G\subseteq GL_n(V)$ for which the set $\cup_{g\in G}\mathbb{Z}n_A(g)$ is cyclic group.